# Visual Studio 2010, is there some way I can add a prefix e.g. (C:\) to #include a massive amount of <boost/asio.hpp> headers?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I got some C++ Boost code from a tutorial online. Every path is declared in a  format.

Is there a way include Visual Studio to add a prefix that will for the who project, allow me to #include files in that format?

It is one header file after another and they all reference more header files in that format.

I know QT Creator has an #INCLUDEPATHS option where it allows you to import a directory and then reference straight from that.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
#include <boost\asio.hpp>
using namespace boost;

class SimpleSerial
{
public:
/**
 * Constructor.
 * \param port device name, example "/dev/ttyUSB0" or "COM4"
 * \param baud_rate communication speed, example 9600 or 115200
 * \throws boost::system::system_error if cannot open the
 * serial device
 */
SimpleSerial(std::string port, unsigned int baud_rate)
: io(), serial(io,port)
{
    serial.set_option(boost::asio::serial_port_base::baud_rate(baud_rate));
}

/**
 * Write a string to the serial device.
 * \param s string to write
 * \throws boost::system::system_error on failure
 */
void writeString(std::string s)
{
    boost::asio::write(serial,boost::asio::buffer(s.c_str(),s.size()));
}

/**
 * Blocks until a line is received from the serial device.
 * Eventual '\n' or '\r\n' characters at the end of the string are removed.
 * \return a string containing the received line
 * \throws boost::system::system_error on failure
 */
std::string readLine()
{
    //Reading data char by char, code is optimized for simplicity, not speed
    using namespace boost;
    char c;
    std::string result;
    for(;;)
    {
        asio::read(serial,asio::buffer(&c,1));
        switch(c)
        {
            case '\r':
                break;
            case '\n':
                return result;
            default:
                result+=c;
        }
    }
}

private:
boost::asio::io_service io;
boost::asio::serial_port serial;
};
```

Comment: Could you tell us which errors you are getting. I do not understand what "not recognizing" means to you.

Comment: Hi Daramarak, essentially Visual Studio is not recognizing these files because of their include paths and the fact I have not added any sort of prefix or imported their containing directory.

Comment: Using C:\ in #include is just awful. Who would do such a thing? Just remove it, a forget that you ever saw it.

Comment: Visual Studio recognizes it though, I don't want to use it but I don't know how to reference the hundreds of <boost/asio.hpp> type headers - that's my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on "Project" in the menu bar, and choose "Properties...". Then use the menu tree to go to "Configuration Properties" / "C/C++" / "General" and add the directory to "Additional Include Directories".

Comment: I had actually just done that and it now works - thanks anyway!